# Как сделать нод размером с область видимости камеры?

Tags: godot

Я создаю игру, и во время приближения (изменения параметра **zoom**) мой интерфейс остается на месте и того-же размера, что и был до приближения. Мне нужно сделать так, что бы мой нод интерфейса по размерам стал равен области видимости **Camera2D**. То есть что бы при приближении интерфейс так же оставался на экране, без изменений.

Сначала я просто сделал нод с интерфейсом дочерним по отношению **Camera2D**. Затем я пробовал изменять параметр **scale** у нода с интерфейсом, что бы при приближении интерфейс уменьшался и приближался к центру, но интерфейс тогда сжимался быстрее, чем приближалась камера.

Comment: "мой интерфейс остается на месте и того-же размера, что и был до приближения" и "...при приближении интерфейс так же оставался на экране, без изменений". Догадайтесь почему все хранят молчание. Они не понимают что вам нужно.